# I have created a one-to-one relationship in SQLAlchemy, but I get this error message

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, relationship, one-to-one

I have created a one-to-one relationship in SQLAlchemy, but when I try to retrieve all passengers and their information using a get request, I get this error message: "(TypeError
TypeError: 'PassengerInfoModel' object is not iterable)".

```
@blp.route("/passenger")
class PassengerList(MethodView):
    @blp.response(200, PassengerSchema(many=True))
    def get(self):
        return PassengerModel.query.all()


@blp.route("/passenger/<string:passenger_id>")
class Passenger(MethodView):
    @blp.response(200, PassengerSchema)
    def get(self, passenger_id):
        passenger = PassengerModel.query.get_or_404(passenger_id)
        return passenger

from db import db 

class PassengerInfoModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "passengers_info"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)

    passenger_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("passengers.id"), unique=False, nullable=False
    )
    passenger = db.relationship("PassengerModel", back_populates="passenger_info")


from db import db

class PassengerModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "passengers"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)

    passenger_info = db.relationship("PassengerInfoModel", back_populates="passenger", lazy="select", cascade="all, delete", uselist=False)
```

I tried to send a GET request to the endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:5000/passenger` and `http://127.0.0.1:5000/passenger/passenger_id` but I received an error in Insomnia

```
TypeError
TypeError: 'PassengerInfoModel' object is not iterable
```

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve all passengers? The only route in the question is for retrieving a specific passenger by ID. Did you mean to post the same route twice?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. It was my mistake, and now I have corrected it.

Comment: I want the relationship to be one-to-one and not one-to-many, that's why I use uselist=False